# Как правильно оформить отношения manyToOne oneToMany, не подтягивает данные?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, one-to-many

Пытаюсь связать две таблицы - `posts` и `post_comments`:

```
@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "post")
@Getter
@Setter
@Transient
private Set<PostComment> postComments = new HashSet<>();
```

---

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "post_id")
private Post post;
```

Чтобы подтягивать данные о комментах не делая новый запрос в базу.

Метод поста `getPostComments` возвращает количество комментов `0`, хотя они есть.
Подскажите что не так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего вы вызываете метод `getPostComments` вне транзакции, которая вытаскивала данные из базы, т.к. у вас не указан тип `fetch`, он по умолчанию `Lazy`, но данные могут быть извлечены только в рамках одной транзакции.

Для того, чтобы просто не делать доп. запрос, то можно указать `FetchType.EAGER`, который вытащит все данные из таблицы при запросе сущности `Post`

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "post", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
```

Comment: а в Intellij IDEA разрабатываете?

Comment: В `Edit Configurations` установите галочку `Enable debug ouput`, в логах должны появится строки запроса к базе, посмотрите, там есть join?

Comment: нужно выбрать вашу конфигурацию запуска `Spring Boot`, там будет выпадающее меню Spring Boot, нажмите на стрелочку, там должно быть

Comment: from tag2post posts0_ inner join posts post1_ on posts0_.post_id=post1_.id left outer join users user2_ on post1_.moderator_id=user2_.id left outer join users user3_ on post1_.user_id=user3_.id where posts0_.tag_id=?           Только это - нет моего join. Мщжет ли это быть из-за @jsonignore или @transient?

Comment: а, не заметила, похоже @Transient тут мешает, да, а зачем это вам?

Comment: чтобы в базе не отражалось поле Set<PostComments> postcomments

Comment: Спасибо большое, работаетю. Все из-за @Transient